# Is there a way to get more information from Gatsby's build failures?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, gatsby

I need more information for why my app is failing to build in Gatsby. I run 'gatsby build' and it fails with the following:

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

Is there a way to see something more verbose? I checked npm logs and there was nothing of use there.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   node — inspect node_modules/gatsby/dist/bin/gatsby.js build
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with

`gatsby build --verbose`

although it wasn't as verbose as I'd hoped.